# "anything but" and "anything else but"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Is there any crucial difference between the following? Any scenario where one is correct but the other is not?

> a. We called the house anything but the Pyramid.
>
> b. We called the house anything else but the Pyramid.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80716/discussion-on-question-by-apollyon-anything-but-and-anything-else-but). Questions should include enough detail to get the sort of answer the author would like instead of playing 20 questions in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

**For example**: anything and anything else. Anything else is used in a context where **possible alternatives have been mentioned** or are known to exist in terms of a question. If the  house had been known by other names, the question below makes contextual sense. There are many contexts like this in conversation.

Courtroom lawyer: "Is there **anything else you used** to call the house?" "Did you call the house anything else except the Pyramid?"

Witness' answer: "No, we did not call it **anything else** except the Pyramid." "We didn't call it anything but the Pyramid". Either will do.

Courtroom lawyer: "Did you call the house anything?"

Witness' answer: "We never called it anything but the Pyramid".

In short, personally, I would not use "anything else" here except in a context where various possibilities have been mentioned.

In general, anything and anything else are not 100% the same:

Q: "John, do you want anything"? [from the store or shop] The question is open ended.

A: "No, nothing."

Q: "John, do you want anything else? [something John wants has already been mentioned].
A: "No, nothing else". [except bread]

General statements in a conversation without any previous information or questions about a thing or topic:

"Ah, I never called the house anything but the Pyramid."

**There would be no reason to say "anything else" in this case.**

**Anything else** can refer to a list or several options.

Answer (score 0):

> a. We called the house anything but the Pyramid.

This is when you called the house anything except the Pyramid.
Like there were infinite choices of how you could call the house but except the Pyramid.

whereas

> b. We called the house anything else but the Pyramid.

This is when you already called the house something and then you say this sentence to add into that but specify that the Pyramid was not in one of the choices.

Comment: The first of these is well explained, but I'm not sure adding "even" makes any sense or is really even grammatical.

Comment: By your explanation, the second example should be "We called the house anything else, but **not** The Pyramid." Assuming "Pyramid" is a proper name (due to capitalizing it), "the" needs to be capitalized or omitted.